# What's wrong with my logic (Java syntax)

Tags: java, logic

I'm trying to make a simple program that picks a random number and takes input from the user. The program should tell the user if the guess was hot (-/+ 5 units) or cold, but I never reach the else condition.

Here's the section of code:

```
    public static void giveHint (int guess) {
    int min = guess - 5;
    int max = guess + 5;
    if ((guess > min) && (guess < max)) {
        System.out.println("Hot..");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cold..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Always remember you can expand expressions: `guess > min` ~ `guess > (guess - 5)` ~ hmm?

Comment: @soda : If you found any of the solutions mentioned to be helpful enough to solve your problem, please accept one of them as an answer :)

Answer (score 11):

```
int min = guess - 5;
int max = guess + 5;
```

Should be:

```
int min = actualAnswer - 5;
int max = actualAnswer + 5;
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is your problem:

```
int min = guess - 5;
int max = guess + 5;
```

`min` is ALWAYS lesser than `guess` and `max` is ALWAYS greater than `guess`.

Comment: +1 @BalusC : And I would add, that to correct the logic of this function, the `giveHint` method should take in two parameters: `int guess` and `int actual`.

Comment: I find myself required to state that `min` is less than `guess` (and/)or `max` is greater than `guess`. Consider `guess` as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for example.

Comment: @Tom: yes, leaving overflows outside consideration for this moment ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the actual answer, not just the guess, since the logic can't tell what the appropriate mix/max should be otherwise:

```
public static void giveHint (int guess, int actual) {
    int min = actual - 5;
    int max = actual + 5;
    if ((guess > min) && (guess < max)) {
        System.out.println("Hot..");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cold..");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `guess` as being both `> min` (because `int min = guess - 1`) and `< max` (because `int max = guess + 5`). So of course the first condition is always met. You should be using the actual secret value when defining `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 0):

`min` and `max` should use the value the player is looking for (secret value) rather than the value the player provided. As it is, `min` and `max` change every time the player gives a guess and you're not even using the secret value.

Answer (score -1):

You're calculating min and max based on guess, so guess is always between min and max so (guess > min) && (guess < max) is always true.

Answer (score -1):

Lets use an example:

```
int guess = 20;
int min = guess - 5 = 15;
int max = guess + 5 = 25;
```

therefore

```
min < guess < max
```

Why?

Because you're comparing guess to its self! I think you need to have the actual answer, not the guess

Answer (score -1):

I can't put the full thing in a comment, so here's what your code should be:

```
    public static void giveHint (int guess, int actual) {
    int min = actual - 5;
    int max = actual + 5;
    if ((guess > min) && (guess < max)) {
        System.out.println("Hot..");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cold..");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution :

```
    public static void giveHint (int actual, int guess) {
         if(Math.abs(actual - guess) <= 5) {
             System.out.println("Hot");
             return;
         }

         System.out.println("Cold");
    }
```